# Database size limit for SQL Express Edition

Tags: sql-server

I am new to be SQL Server so I have read that the database size limitation of MS SQL Server 2008 Express Edition is 10 GB. Now my question is can I have multiple databases like Database A with 8 GB and Database B with size 10 GB. I mean is the size limitation for single data database or for the entire SQL Server database size.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 12):

Yes it been increased from 4GB to 10GB

Please refer [SQL Server Express WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx)

In theory you can create multiple databases, which each should be less than 10GB

Answer (score 10):

Check this script on your SQL server -

```
SELECT 
      d.server_name
    , d.sversion_name
    , d.edition
    , max_db_size_in_gb = 
        CASE WHEN engine_edition = 4 -- Express version
            THEN 
                CASE 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2016%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2014%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2012%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008 R2%' THEN 10
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2008%' THEN 4 
                    WHEN d.sversion_name LIKE '%2005%' THEN 4
                END
            ELSE -1 
        END
FROM (
    SELECT 
          sversion_name = SUBSTRING(v.ver, 0, CHARINDEX('-', v.ver) - 1)
        , engine_edition = SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
        , edition = SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
        , server_name = SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
    FROM (SELECT ver = @@VERSION) v
) d
```

*Output for SQL Server 2005 Express -*

```
server_name      sversion_name               edition           max_db_size_in_gb
---------------- --------------------------- ----------------- -----------------
SERV1\SQL2005    Microsoft SQL Server 2005   Express Edition   4
```

*Output for SQL Server 2012 Express -*

```
server_name      sversion_name               edition           max_db_size_in_gb
---------------- --------------------------- ----------------- -----------------
SERV1\SQL2012    Microsoft SQL Server 2012   Express Edition   10
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, yet it got more upvotes than huMpty duMpty's correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not depend how many db is there, `all db size can not exceed 10GB`